# Camel transaction not rolling back on exception

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am playing with Camel 3.13.0 but it looks like the transaction is not rolled back when I use `transacted`. Any idea why?

The code snippet is below:

```
        DataSource dataSource = InOutTest.setupDataSource();
        //Initiate registry, transaction manager, policy
        SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
        DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager =
                new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
        registry.bind("transactionManager", transactionManager);
        SpringTransactionPolicy propagationRequired =
                new SpringTransactionPolicy();
        propagationRequired.setTransactionManager(
                transactionManager);
        propagationRequired.setPropagationBehaviorName(
                "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED");
        registry.bind("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED", propagationRequired);

        //Create context, add sql component
        SqlComponent sqlComponent = new SqlComponent();
        sqlComponent.setDataSource(dataSource);
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        context.addComponent("jmsComponent", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
        context.getComponent("sql", SqlComponent.class).setDataSource(InOutTest.setupDataSource());

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:sqlParam")
                        .transacted("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED")
                        .to("sql:insert into articles(name, category) values ('ActiveMQ', 'activemq')")
                        .process((exchange -> {throw new RuntimeException("Mock Ex");}));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache Camel has long have had the [Transaction EIP pattern](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.15.x/eips/transactional-client.html) supported. One way to configure this pattern, is as you have already did through your Endpoint DSL configuration using `transacted`.

Meanwhile, you are attaching the `PlatformTransationManager` to a `DataSource`:

```
DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager =
            new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
```

Then you are configuring your `SqlComponent` to use a different `DataSource`:

```
context.getComponent("sql", SqlComponent.class).setDataSource(InOutTest.setupDataSource());
```

You should use the same managed `DataSource` used to configure your `PlatformTransationManager` by removing the aforementioned line and you should be good to go.